# JS onclick event from loop

Tags: javascript, onclicklistener

I have a problem with JavaScript and the onclick event. I want to define the onclick event from an element I created in a loop. My code looks somehow like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.entries.length; i++) {
  var entry = result.entries[i];
  var adder = document.createElement('span');
  adder.innerHTML = '+';
  adder.onclick = function () {
    addFeed(entry.title, entry.url);
    backButton();
  };
  container.appendChild(adder);
}
```

The problem is, that this code creates an event listener like this:

```
listenerBody: "function () {addFeed(entry.title, entry.url); backButton();}"
```

But I need the value of entry.title and entry.url like:

```
listenerBody: "function () {addFeed('ABC', 'http://example.com'); backButton();}"
```

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just hit against a thing in javascript called hoisting and closure looping.

What is happening is that your loop continues, and when the onclick function is triggered, what you have in the `entry` variable is the last element of `result.entries`.

To solve this you can lock it in a closure (example):

```
function setOnClickEvent(element, entryValue) {
  element.onclick = function () {
    addFeed(entryValue.title, entryValue.url);
    backButton();
  };
}

for (var i = 0; i < result.entries.length; i++) {
  var entry = result.entries[i];
  var adder = document.createElement('span');
  adder.innerHTML = '+';
  setOnClickEvent( adder, entry)
  container.appendChild(adder);
}
```